# Search Woocommerce product titles only

Tags: functions, search, plugins

Limiting post search to titles only is a breeze, but WooCommerce's post types don't abide by this rule. I have tried modifying the code below to be specific to products but am not having any luck.

```
function search_by_title_only( $search, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if ( empty( $search ) )
        return $search; // skip processing - no search term in query
    $q = $wp_query->query_vars;
    $n = ! empty( $q['exact'] ) ? '' : '%';
    $search = '';
    $searchand = '';
    foreach ( (array) $q['search_terms'] as $term ) {
        $term = esc_sql( like_escape( $term ) );
        $search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
        $searchand = ' AND ';
    }
    if ( ! empty( $search ) ) {
        $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
            $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
    }
    return $search;
}
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'search_by_title_only', 500, 2 );
```

I'm not sure if I'm not using the right [hooks](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/) or if I'm barking up the wrong tree altogether. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the free [Relevanssi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relevanssi/) plugin does this rather well. I was afraid it would only search posts and not custom post types, but it does it all... and rather well! It only requires a simple filter added to your theme's `functions.php` file to get it to omit the body content:

```
// search titles only (relevanssi plugin)
add_filter('relevanssi_index_content', 'contentoff');
function contentoff() {
    return false;
}
```

alternatively you can have it omit titles (don't use the two together or you'll be searching nothing!

```
// search titles only (relevanssi plugin)
add_filter('relevanssi_index_titles', 'contentoff');
function contentoff() {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: ...and there's the added bonus of it returning search results by relevance instead of by date or name.